# Node.Js -> Получить параметр из URL

Tags: node.js

Добрый день.

Столкнулся с банальной задачей - получить параметр из Url.

> url.parse(request.url).query); получаю из URL
>
> http://localhost:8888/delay?cat=betty я смог получить параметры: cat=betty
>
> url.parse(request.url).query["cat"]; - > undefined

**Как можно программно получить коллекцию параметров а потом по каждому из них получить значение? Такое здесь возможно?**

Спасибо

Answer (score -1):

https://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html

```
querystring.parse(url.parse(s).search.substr(1))
```

Пример:

```
> qs = url.parse("/delay?cat=betty")
Url {
  protocol: null,
  slashes: null,
  auth: null,
  host: null,
  port: null,
  hostname: null,
  hash: null,
  search: '?cat=betty',
  query: 'cat=betty',
  pathname: '/delay',
  path: '/delay?cat=betty',
  href: '/delay?cat=betty' }
> s = qs.search
'?cat=betty'
> querystring.parse(s)
{ '?cat': 'betty' }
> querystring.parse(s.substr(1))
{ cat: 'betty' }
> f = s => querystring.parse(url.parse(s).search.substr(1))
[Function]
> f("/any?x=12&y=123&smth")
{ x: '12', y: '123', smth: '' }
```